# Is there anything that provides the kind of support PHP's filter_var does in ColdFusion?

Tags: security, validation, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, sanitize

I've found [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to be **extremely** useful in validating and sanitizing user input with PHP, but I've yet to find anything even remotely as convenient in ColdFusion (more specifically, CF8).

Obviously I can hack together something using [REReplace](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions_m-r_35.html#135742), but that would take significantly more time to code up and would be much uglier than using the pre-defined filters available in PHP. Is there a more efficient way or do I just need to bite the bullet?

Comment: A function that returns a string or `false` seems a bit rubbish. CFML has the function **[isValid](http://cfdocs.org/isvalid)** which seems to otherwise do the same job (it always returns a boolean).

Comment: Have you poked around at http://cflib.org ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, @AlEverett! I hadn't seen that before, but I will definitely look into it. Some of the libraries I see right off the bat look pretty useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three different options available to you.  Since you're attempting to manage user input, I assume you're using forms.  [isValid](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_in-k_37.html) most closely mimics your functionality, allowing you to check if a value specified matches either a data type or a regular expression and returns true or false, and includes attributes by default to define a range.  It does not support the ability to create a custom 'filter' beyond defining a regular expression however.

The second option would be using [cfparam](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_01.html#1101730) tags on your POST processing page, which allows you to specify the existance of a variable, test against a data type or define a regular expression, and optionally assign a default value if the variable doesn't exist.  If you attempt to process a page where the field is not defined and no default value is assigned however, ColdFusion throws an error.

Finally, you can do validation by using cfform and [cfinput](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_i_07.html) fields on your form itself; which allows for client-side data validation for existence and types (it also supports server-side validation but it's implementation is sloppy), regular expressions, and input masking: taking user-inputted data and conforming it to a specific format (like adding dashes to phone numbers and zip codes).

Comment: Thanks! Between isValid and cfparam I can find something for what I need.